# Parenthesis to switch between namespace and class?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Working with legacy javascript I came across roughly the following js code

```
// module1.js
class Class {
    constructor() { console.log('hello') }
}
const exported = {
    Class: Class,
}
module.exports = exported
```

which is used like so in typescript

```
// module2.ts
import Module1 from './module1'

class Subclass extends Module1.Class { // <<
    ...
```

here vscode shows an error and the following type hint

```
(alias) const Module1: {
    Class: typeof Class;
}
import Module1
----------------------------------------
Cannot find namespace 'Module1'. ts(2503)
```

The thing I am curious about is after playing around I added parenthesis like so

```
class Subclass extends (Module1).Class {
```

and vscode no longer shows the error. What is this error and what is the meaning of those parenthesis? I couldn't find anything regarding namespaces, import aliases, ...

There is by the way no error when compiling with tsc, the code works either way.

some relevant parts of tsconfig (nodejs, ts 4.8.2)

```
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
```

Note: it also makes no difference if the file is imported via `import Module1 = require('./module1')` so I guess it's not related to `esModuleInterop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the error is correct. Module1 is not a namespace, it's a value. You can't use the dot operator on a value. You can use the dot operator on a namespace, but not on a value.

The parentheses are a type assertion. They tell the compiler that you know what you're doing, and that Module1 is a namespace. The compiler will then allow you to use the dot operator on it.

Comment: Do you have any reference to documentation for that?

Comment: I honestly don't remember where I read about it. I've been spending a lot of the day on stackoverflow and researching various topics. But I'll look for it and let you know.